# Why was this question protected?

Tags: discussion, specific-question, moderation, protected-questions

To be clear, I'm not *complaining* about this question being protected.  But I'm not sure what *prompted* this question to be protected, given that as far as I know only *one* answer got into the stuff in the linked comment (and said answer was subsequently deleted)?

[Is there a canonical behavior for the behavior of an object that would have its weight/mass reduced below 0?](https://rpg.stackexchange.com/questions/149086/is-there-a-canonical-behavior-for-the-behavior-of-an-object-that-would-have-its?noredirect=1#comment386180_149086)

Comment: Presumably because it has 4 deleted answers so far, and since it's not about D&D 5e it's highly likely to get more.

Answer (score 17, accepted):

There are actually 4 deleted answers to that question (which takes [10K rep to see](https://rpg.stackexchange.com/help/privileges/moderator-tools)).

2 of those answers are from brand new users, 1 is from a new user that has the [associated bonus rep](https://stackoverflow.blog/2009/07/08/cross-site-account-associations/), and 1 is from a fairly new, low rep user.

None of the 4 answers submitted answer the question asking about *canonical* behaviour from Anima Beyond Fantasy sources and instead try to use real-world physics as a basis (something that doesn't generally apply to fantasy settings) or other off-topic-for-the-question reasoning.

I [protected](https://rpg.stackexchange.com/help/privileges/protect-questions) the question to simply prevent *more* off-topic/non-answer answers from new users swarming in.

Comment: Ah.  I only caught the one that went on about behavior in AD&D.